# Recommend any "best first IETF RFC to read"

Tags: standards, rfc

If you would advise people to start reading RFC's, which would you recommend people start with?

It should be something more complex than [RFC 863 (Discard Protocol)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc863), but something simpler than rocket science :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the RFC about [Simple Mail Transfer Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321). It concerns everyone of us and is not that hard to read/understand.

And for fun, there is always [IP Over Avian Carriers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2549) ;)

Comment: RFC 821: It has state diagrams, formal definition of protocol grammer, glossary, references and does not draw material from too many RFC's. Also most people being familiar with SMTP terminology helps.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget RFC 1178 - Choosing a name for your computer!